# I am getting this error cannot find element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
<span class="scbyf hjkDiy" type="button" display="block">Items</span>
```

need help:

```
Items_list = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.scbyf.hjkDiy).click()
```

I tried with this as well.

```
Items_list = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.scbyf.hjkDiy[type=Items]").click()
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that there is no such element.  Can you include a sample of the html?

Comment: That element is a span, not a div.  Why are you using div in the css selector?

Answer (score 0):

HTML you have shared having `span` element but you are using `div` ,
So You have to replace your Locator with below

Your Locator : `div.scbyf.hjkDiy`
needs to replace with below

```
span.scbyf.hjkDiy
```

So your final should look like,

`Items_list = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.scbyf.hjkDiy).click()`.

Answer (score 0):

please use xpath,

```
yourEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='scbyf hjkDiy'])")
```